# Trailing quote in echo statement breaking output

Tags: php, echo

I hate to ask such a simple question, but I'm completely stumped. I'm trying to output

```
<input type='radio' name='state' value='VALUE' /> OTHERVALUE
```

which is absurdly simple, but something is breaking. My statement,

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="state" value="' . $abbr . '" /> ' . $state;
```

causes an error that stops output. I've also tried the following variations while debugging, all of which look like they should work to me:

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='state' value='";
echo '<input type=\'radio\' name=\'state\' value=\'';
echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"state\" value=\"";
```

In every case, removing the last ', ", \', or \" before the closing single/double         quote fixes the problem. I can work around this, but I've spend like 20+ minutes now debugging this. What is causing this? Is there a gap in my knowledge of how ' and " work?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: There isn't an error, it just stops output.

Comment: And why are you outputting unclosed tags to begin with? The browser will obviously not display anything until the next `">`.

Comment: I updated it. You can see the full output here, http://pastebin.com/yE9eunqx it doesn't print *up to* the open quote, it doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing the end double quotes and single quotes.

`echo '<input type="radio" name="state" value=""'`

`echo "<input type='radio' name='state' value=''";`

`echo '<input type=\'radio\' name=\'state\' value=\'\'';`

`echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"state\" value=\"\"";`

If you want a value inside:

`echo '<input type="radio" name="state" value="' . $value . '">';`

Comment: My god, it's this simple. My original statement before debugging was more complex, and I realized while responding to you that I hadn't closed the last " after I output the variable, doing that fixed it. It makes no sense to me (the output doesn't stop at the last ", it doesn't print anything), but I guess it's working.

Comment: @Kolink 's answer sums up *why* you were experiencing that "error". There was technically no PHP error, so this was really an html error causing the rest of the page to not "exist" (but rather within that `<input>`'s attributes as Kolink said.

Answer (score 1):

If you're outputting incomplete tags, the browser will greedily grab everything afterwards, treating them as attributes, until it finally finds a `>`.

In future, use View Source to see the raw output of the script, and you will see these things more clearly.

Comment: That's the thing, I did. The output is here: http://pastebin.com/yE9eunqx 

It doesn't print *anything*, not even the part before the open quote.

Comment: Is error reporting on?

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo "<input type='radio' name='state' value='$variable'";`

or

Try `echo '<input type="radio" name="state" value="' . $variable . '"';`

If you start with double quotes (i.e. `echo " hello to 'this' $variable ";`)
 you can include variables within those quotes, and you can include single quotes

If you start with single quotes, you can't include inline variables, but you can include double quotes: `echo 'hello to "this" $variable';` will output `hello to "this" $variable`.

It looks like you know this, but you may just be forgetting to close a quote here and there.

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="state" value="'
```

will output `<input type="radio" name="state" value="` notice the missing close quote, and close tag!

Comment: That's the thing. It didn't output *anything*. http://pastebin.com/yE9eunqx is the full output, the <input should be on the line immediately following the <form>.

Comment: oh, interesting. Yea, I have seen that happen. You can turn error_reporting on to see a line number, or check your error_log file. Or just check where the html stops (the form in this case). That's my usual debugging go-tos.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it's a school server so I don't have access to those, but good to know :P

Comment: you can always turn on error_reporting (i think). It'll show the error on the page (before it stops working and shows a blank screen :)  )